# AWS Java Lambda, occasional timeout when getting item from DynamoDB (enhanced DynamoDB client)

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

I have an AWS Java Lambda function handler. It does two things.

- step 1. calls another Lambda function that creates a new item in DynamoDB (with conditional write) (`software.amazon.awssdk.enhanced.dynamodb.DynamoDbEnhancedClient`
  is used for DB connection.)
- step 2. gets the item from DynamoDB by key

Usually step 2 only takes some tens of milliseconds to get item from DynamoDB. However, once every few months, step 2 can take up to 10 seconds or more, causing the Lambda function timeout failure. As it is very rare, I am not able to reproduce this issue.

I expect to reproduce the issue and prevent it from happening again.

Comment: Are the lambda functions running inside VPC ?

Comment: Yes these two Lambda functions are in the same VPC.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply prevent this by setting your request timeouts. If a request typically responses in 10s of millis then it doesn't make sense for the client to wait more than 10 seconds, that's a huge difference.

Set your request timeouts to be 1 second (very lenient) for example, so that any request that may be stuck will be killed and an SDK retry will return the item in 1.1 second.

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/tuning-aws-java-sdk-http-request-settings-for-latency-aware-amazon-dynamodb-applications/

Here is an example of how I configure my Enhanced Client:

```java
public static DynamoDbClient dynamoDbClient() {

    /*
    apiCallAttemptTimeout() => Comparable with => withRequestTimeout()
    The amount of time to wait for the http request to complete
    before giving up and timing out.
    This value should always be positive, if present.
     */
    final Duration ATTEMPT_TIMEOUT = Duration.ofMillis(10);
    /*
    apiCallTimeout() => Comparable with => withClientExecutionTimeout()
    The amount of time to allow the client to complete the execution of an API call.
    This timeout covers the entire client execution except for marshalling.
    This includes request handler execution, all HTTP requests including retries, unmarshalling, etc.
    This value should always be positive, if present.
     */
    final Duration API_CALL_TIMEOUT = Duration.ofMillis(1500);

    /*
    connectionTimeout() => Comparable with =>  withConnectionTimeout()
    The amount of time to wait when initially establishing a connection before giving up and timing out.
    A duration of 0 means infinity, and is not recommended.
     */
    final Duration CONNECTION_TIMEOUT = Duration.ofMillis(5000);

    /*
    socketTimeout() => Comparable with =>  withSocketTimeout()
    The amount of time to wait for data to be transferred over an established, open connection before the connection is timed out.
    A duration of 0 means infinity, and is not recommended.
     */
    final Duration SOCKET_TIMEOUT = Duration.ofMillis(5500);

    /*
    Configure the maximum number of times that a single request should be retried, assuming it fails for a retryable error.
     */
    final int RETRY_LIMIT = 3;

    // HTTP Client Builder
    UrlConnectionHttpClient.Builder httpClientBuilder = UrlConnectionHttpClient.builder()
            .connectionTimeout(CONNECTION_TIMEOUT)
            .socketTimeout(SOCKET_TIMEOUT);

    // Retry Policy Builder
    RetryPolicy.Builder retryBuilder = RetryPolicy.builder()
            .numRetries(RETRY_LIMIT);

    // Override Client Config Builder
    ClientOverrideConfiguration.Builder clientOverrideBuilder =
            ClientOverrideConfiguration.builder()
                    .apiCallAttemptTimeout(ATTEMPT_TIMEOUT)
                    .apiCallTimeout(API_CALL_TIMEOUT)
                    .retryPolicy(retryBuilder.build());

    // Return Custom Client
    return DynamoDbClient.builder()
            .httpClientBuilder(httpClientBuilder)
            .overrideConfiguration(clientOverrideBuilder.build())
            .build();
}
```

```java
DynamoDbEnhancedClient enhancedClient = DynamoDbEnhancedClient.builder()
                    .dynamoDbClient(dynamoDbClient())
                    .build();
```

Comment: It seems the link you provided does not use DynamoDB enhanced client. If I use the [enhanced client] (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DynamoDBEnhanced.html), how can I configure the timeout/retry for DynamoDB connection?

Comment: https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java-v2/blob/master/http-client-spi/src/main/java/software/amazon/awssdk/http/SdkHttpConfigurationOption.java

Comment: I am using this enhanced dynamoDB and I still don't see how I can configure the timeout/retry values. (https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java-v2/blob/43e31851ca4804511acea3649385b3ee1a8788cc/services-custom/dynamodb-enhanced/src/main/java/software/amazon/awssdk/enhanced/dynamodb/DynamoDbEnhancedClient.java)

Comment: Added an example for you.